# webmethod with if statements

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i have repeater that get data by paging after scroll down,and the same functionality (get data by paging) after user click over the button.

I have webmethod that get those parameters like the described below

```
   [WebMethod]
   public static string GetCustomers(int pageIndex)
   {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    return GetCustomersData(pageIndex,false,"").GetXml();
   }
```

The same function GetCustomersData(); is running after button click

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    rptCustomers.DataSource = GetCustomersData(1,true,"22");
    rptCustomers.DataBind();
}
```

the first webmethod is running after jquery call, and the second one it running after the user click the button.

The problem is , in the Javascript file after scrolling down, the webmethod running.

How to stop that, I mean if the user click over the button. i want to disable the javascript or to stop the webmethod. even if the javascript detect that there is scroll down and the webmethod run

The imageButton click is

```
 protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    rptCustomers.DataSource = GetCustomersData(1,true,"22");
    rptCustomers.DataBind();
}
```

Thanks for adivse

Comment: Please post your html code for the image button

Comment: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);` Is that just for testing?

Comment: sleep(2000)Yes it's just for testing,

Comment: Updated - the click image button

Comment: The click was already there. I was referring to the html code <asp:ImageButton ???

Comment: <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
                                ImageUrl="~/Recources/WebImages/m7Design.jpg" Width="400px" 
                                onclick="ImageButton1_Click" />